# (New) DNS Issues

Tags: bug, status-completed

The following two addresses are not currently resolving to the expected webpages:

1. http://www.askubuntu.com (see [downforeveryoneorjustme.com](http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/www.askubuntu.com))
2. http://chat.ubuntu.stackexchange.com (see [downforeveryoneorjustme.com](http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/chat.ubuntu.stackexchange.com))

Comment: Yep. Can confirm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be resolved - please let us know if you still find an issue.